# Dc.js brushing lag. Filtering multiple times unlike dc.js version 1.3

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc.js with crossfilter on the server. So each brushing event is basically an AJAX call to the server which returns the result. 
Now when I am using brushing with dc.js version > 1.3.0 I am getting a huge lag. I notice that it sends multiple filtering requests to the server while the brush is being dragged.
This wasnt the case with dc.js version 1.3.0 where in the filtering would happen only when the user finished the dragging(on mousedown or something). Again this is my assumption.

I looked at this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dc-js-user-group/3AlQht_8Eqs/6DSzEgDWAYkJ and set dc.EVENT_DELAY=0 but even that is not helping. If someone could help me disable this continuous filtering on mouse drag, that would be great. I just need filtering to be done once the brush has been set.

I need to use version 1.7+ to get support for rangeChart().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set EVENT_DELAY to something other than 0 so as to throttle events. I believe the delay is in milliseconds, so maybe 200 or 300 would be a good value?

Comment: Yeah, setting it to zero will cause many more events, more like the crossfilter demo. But if it's not zero there will be a delay. :-(  I believe you'll have to go into the code to change this. Will try to suggest ideas soon, but for now, look at how `dc.trigger` is implemented and where it's called from the brush. And please file an issue!

Comment: @Gordon Would it make sense for dc.js to offer a chart option to only apply the filter on "brushend" rather than on "brush" events? That seems to be what he's looking for, and I could see it being useful in situations where people want less dynamism in the chart as well, as this can be confusing or computationally too expensive sometimes.

Comment: Ok thanks for the insight! :) I changed the dc.js code to have "brushEnd" event(which was removed in version 1.7.1). I removed the filtering code from the "brush" event and added to it "brushEnd".

Comment: @EthanJewett, yes, definitely.. [Here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/627) is the issue lastlegion filed (thanks!), for further discussion. I haven't yet thought of anything more general than a boolean option, but I think there are some interesting possibilities for specifying a policy by passing a function.